# Referring to column values directly without using variables in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is there a way in T-SQL (SQL Server 2005) to assign a whole record to a *record variable* and then refer to the particular values using column names?

I mean, instead of:

```
select @var1 = col1,
       @var2 = col2
from mytable
where ID = 1;
```

and referring to them as `@var1` and `@var2`, something like

```
@record = 
select col1, col2
from mytable
where ID = 1;
```

and referring to them like `@record.col1` and `@record.col2` .

I am beginner in t-sql, so hopefully the question is not too trivial.

Comment: SQL Server has no concept of a "record" - that's programmer-speak :-) SQL Server (and any RDBMS really) is strictly rows and columns - you can select columns, you can restrict rows - that's about it.

Comment: Short answer: No, there is no composite variables, except table variables in T-SQL and as some answers point out, table variables are selected out of just like a table.

Comment: @marc_s: Oracle's PL/SQL can have variables with a record type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buried in the [Transact SQL documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx) I came across this restriction on variables:

> Variables can be used only in expressions, not in place of object names or keywords.

Since you'd need to use an object name to qualify a column I don't believe that this is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a table variable and select the whole resultset into it:

```
DECLARE  @tt TABLE (col1 INT, col2 INT)

INSERT
INTO    @tt
SELECT  col1, col2
FROM    mytable
WHERE   id = 1
```

, but you cannot access its data except than in the `SELECT` query as well.

With pure `TSQL` (that it without custom datatypes) the thing you ask is impossible.

Comment: I thought such a thing should be quite straightforward in a language like TSQL. Yet another MS disappointment.. I don't understand why I have to define N variables to be able to refer to N columns of a table. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you are a programmer ... look at linq maybe as it does what you want.

Comment: "sounds like you are a programmer" is the best quote here I've seen so far.

Comment: linq seems to me as an overkill in my case. I would go with one-by-one assignment instead.. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: lol ok dumb thing to say ... but it was a database question ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temporary table and SELECT...INTO to avoid specifying the column names at the beginning :

```
SELECT Field1, Field2
INTO #TempTable
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTable.MyID = 1
```

but of course you'll still need the FROM #TempTable part when referring to the column names.

```
SELECT Field1, Field2
FROM #TempTable
```

and of course to remember to drop the table at the end :

```
DROP #TempTable
```

The app code is where you'd normally refer to a single row at a time as a variable.

Comment: You are right saying "The app code is where you'd normally refer to a single row at a time as a variable." Maybe I should consider a re-design.

Answer (score 1):

You could use XML, but you'd have to play with this...

```
DECLARE @MyRecord xml
DECLARE @Mytable TABLE (col1 int NOT NULL, col2 varchar(30) NOT NULL)

INSERT @Mytable (col1, col2) VALUES (1, 'bob')

select @MyRecord =
    (SELECT *
    from @Mytable
    where col1 = 1
    FOR XML AUTO)

SELECT @myRecord.value('./@col', 'int') --also @myRecord.value('@col', 'int')

--gives error

Msg 2390, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
XQuery [value()]: Top-level attribute nodes are not supported
```